# PHP: Values returned by ref from functions seems to get copied on multiple assignments

Tags: php, memory, reference

When a value being returned from a function by ref is assigned to multiple variables, assignments after the first one seems to copy the value.

The code I used to test it is:

```
root@kelso:/tmp# php -r 'function &bar() {static $x; if (NULL === $x) {$x=range(1,99999);}; return $x;};  var_dump(memory_get_usage()); bar(); var_dump(memory_get_usage()); $b1=bar(); var_dump(memory_get_usage()); $b2=bar(); var_dump(memory_get_usage()); $b3=bar(); var_dump(memory_get_usage());'  
int(95872)  
int(20345912)  
int(20346040)  
int(33395000)  
int(46444184)
```

Same code, formatted and with comments:

```
function &bar() {static $x; if (NULL === $x) {$x=range(1,99999);}; return $x;};  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // starting out with 95872  
bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // 20345912 - first call to bar() sets the static $x  
$b1=bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // 20346040 - first assignment consumes almost no memory  
$b2=bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // 33395000 - second assignment seems to copy it  
$b3=bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // 46444184 - third assignment seems to copy it again
```

Is there any reason only the first assignment is returned by ref while other are copied?

For comparison, this is what happens when the value is not returned from a function:

```
root@kelso:/tmp# php -r 'var_dump(memory_get_usage());; $a=range(1,99999); var_dump(memory_get_usage()); $b=&$a; var_dump(memory_get_usage()); $c=&$a; var_dump(memory_get_usage());'  
int(92224)  
int(20342024)  
int(20342152)  
int(20342280)
```

Same code, formatted:

```
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(92224)  
$a=range(1,99999);  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(20342024)  
$b=&$a;  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(20342152)  
$c=&$a;  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); // int(20342280)
```

As you can see, almost no memory is used for multiple assignments by reference.

Before posting this to bugs.php.net, I was wondering if its an expected behavior that I don't know of. Anyone knows why it happens?

Comment: *(reference)* [Copy-on-Write in the PHP Language (pdf)](http://www.trl.ibm.com/people/mich/pub/200901_popl2009phpsem.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The & is required for both the function and the call. So the following

```
function &bar() {
static $x; 
if (NULL === $x) {
    $x=range(1,99999);
}
return $x;}

var_dump(memory_get_usage());
bar();
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); 
$b1=&bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); 
$b2=&bar();  
var_dump(memory_get_usage()); 
$b3=&bar(); 
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
```

Will give you

```
int(54296)
int(7843472)
int(7843520)
int(7843520)
int(7843544)
```

Comment: Great, thanks.

I still don't quite understand why defining the function with & isn't enough? shouldn't it tell PHP to return it by reference? What does function &foo tell it to do, than?

Also, why did the first assignment worked as I expected and only the second one started copying it?

Comment: And another thing- even without any "&", not in the function definition and not when calling it - shouldn't the copy-on-write return it by reference and copy it only when I modify something?

Comment: It is my understanding that the & on the function tells the interpreter that it CAN be return by reference and the one on the set itself says that you are WANTING to set by reference. As far as the difference on the first and the second, I cannot comment on that because I'm simply not sure.

On your second comment because it is coming from a function the interpreter treats them as separate "instances" of the var because the function isn't set to return by reference. 

Hope this cleared a little up for you

Comment: So basically copy-on-write doesn't work on values returned from a function, just when assigning one variable to another or on variables passed as arguments to a function?  
  
Any chance someone else might know the difference between the first assignment from a function to the next ones?